# Forwarding Traffic With SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Under my wireless network I have certain ports blocked (in this example 2467 [its randomly assigned]). I have an SSH box which I can access the host and port as intended.

How would I do this?

Example: 
(on wireless network) ---> Personal Server
On my personal server I would want to foward all personal traffic from the SSH client on that port and have it sent from the personal server.

I know how to do this HTTP, however I am unable to do this with SVN traffic. Does anyone have any idea on this?

I'm not trying to access resources on my personal server, I just need my personal server to relay this over SSH. [I'm allowed to SSH out on the Wireless connection]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
#Forward local traffic on port 9999 to squid on ssh server
#  Set browser proxy server to 127.0.0.1 port 9999
SSH_SERVER=ip.of.personal.server
ssh -L 9999:$SSH_SERVER:3128 $SSH_SERVER

#Forward local traffic on port 8888 to pop3 mail server
MAIL_SERVER=ip.of.mail.server
ssh -L 8888:$MAIL_SERVER:110 $SSH_SERVER
```

Comment: I wouldn't have the information of the SVN server before hand.